# ios swift core graphics - string is upside down

Tags: ios, swift, string, core-graphics

When I want to draw a String in a CGContext, the text appears upside down.

I know this subject has already been posted here, but none of the solution are working for me.

I do flip the context:

```
graphContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
graphContext.translateBy(
        x: CGFloat(0.0),
        y: CGFloat(-1.0 * graphSize.h))
```

I tried to do the same with the textMatrix too, but this has no effect at all on the result.

Full project sources are here: [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cejw0mt6qm48577/AABVkjePT9BPgEJuBQu5o38Ta?dl=0)
Screen shot here: [screen shot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b34ra3v0ns80zb0/screenshot.tiff?dl=0)

Can't figure why it is not working.

Thanks

My draw method:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let graphSize = GSize(
            w: Double(self.frame.width),
            h: Double(self.frame.height))

        rebaseAreas(graphSize: graphSize)

        graphContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        graphContext.saveGState()

        // Flip the context coordinates, in iOS only
        graphContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        graphContext.translateBy(
            x: CGFloat(0.0),
            y: CGFloat(-1.0 * graphSize.h))


        // this has no effect, I can delete it and nothing changes
        graphContext.textMatrix = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2.0, y: -2.0)


        drawBackground(
            inRect: graph_drawing_rect,
            inContext: graphContext)


        drawGuidelines(
            vAxis: vAxis,
            hAxis: hAxis,
            inRect: serie_drawing_rect,
            inContext: graphContext)


        drawSerie(
            points,
            inRect: serie_drawing_rect,
            inContext: graphContext)


        drawTitle(
            inRect: graph_drawing_rect,
            inContext: graphContext)


        drawVAxisLabels(
            vAxis: vAxis,
            inRect: x_labels_drawing_rect,
            inContext: graphContext)


        drawHAxisLabels(
            hAxis: hAxis,
            inRect: y_labels_drawing_rect,
            inContext: graphContext)

        graphContext.restoreGState()
    }
```

And my drawTitle method:

```
func drawTitle(
        inRect rect: GRect,
        inContext context: CGContext) {

        // saving the calling state
        context.saveGState()

        let title = titleLabelText

        let lblAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: titleFont,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: title_font_color,
            ] as [String : Any]

        let origin = CGPoint(
            x: title_label_position.x * rect.w,
            y: title_label_position.y * rect.h)

        let drawRect = CGRect(
            origin: origin,
            size: title.size(attributes: lblAttributes))

        title.draw(
            in: drawRect,
            withAttributes: lblAttributes)

        // returning the calling state
        graphContext.restoreGState()
    }
```

Comment: What I did: For your graphics context I changed the scaleBy to scaleBy(1.0, 1.0) and for the translateBy I changed it to translateBy(0.0, -1.0) and it displayed the text correctly. Unfortunately it still looks like the positioning is off because this doesn't look much like a graph imo but the text is right.

Comment: That was the problem. I wasn't able to get and the lines and the text right at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using UIKit's string-drawing support. UIKit adds the method you're using, `drawInRect:withAttributes:`, to `NSString`.

UIKit sets the text matrix when it draws the string. (You can set a breakpoint on `CGContextSetTextMatrix` to verify this.) This means that your attempt to set `textMatrix` has no effect.

UIKit expects the graphics context's origin to be at the top left of the drawing area, and it expects y coordinates to increase toward the bottom of the drawing area. You have flipped the direction of the y axis, so UIKit ends up drawing the text upside down.

Since you can't fix this using the text matrix, you have to fix it using the transform matrix. You need to translate the origin to the top-left corner of the rectangle that should contain the text, flip the y axis, draw the text at the origin, and then restore the transform matrix.

You can wrap this in an extension method on `NSString`:

```
private extension String {

    func drawFlipped(in rect: CGRect, withAttributes attributes: [String: Any]) {
        guard let gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        gc.saveGState()
        defer { gc.restoreGState() }
        gc.translateBy(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.origin.y + rect.size.height)
        gc.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: rect.size), withAttributes: attributes)
    }

}
```

Then you can use your extension method instead of `draw(in:withAttributes:)`. For example, here's a replacement for your `drawTitle(inRect:inContext:)` method:

```
func drawTitle(
    inRect rect: GRect,
    inContext context: CGContext) {

    let title = titleLabelText

    let lblAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: titleFont,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: title_font_color,
        ] as [String : Any]

    let origin = CGPoint(
        x: title_label_position.x * rect.w,
        y: title_label_position.y * rect.h)

    let drawRect = CGRect(
        origin: origin,
        size: title.size(attributes: lblAttributes))

    title.drawFlipped(in: drawRect, withAttributes: lblAttributes)
}
```

Result:

[image: screen shot with correctly drawn title]

Note that I only fixed `drawTitle(inRect:inContext:)`, so all of the other text is still upside-down.

Comment: Works fine!!! Thank you. Btw, is there another to draw strings without using UIKit?

Comment: UIKit uses [Core Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533) under the hood. You can use Core Text directly, but I wouldn't recommend it for something this simple. I have written code to draw graphs like this, but I just use a separate `UILabel` for each label and only use Core Graphics to draw the actual data points / lines / bars / etc.